# Pandas showing Ker Error with mean function

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Getting the `KeyError: 'BasePay'` for the `BasePay` element while its therein the DataFrame but missing while using `mean()` function.

My pandas version is `'0.23.3'` python3.6.3

```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> salDataF = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv', low_memory=False)
    >>> salDataF.head()
       Id       EmployeeName                                        JobTitle    BasePay OvertimePay   OtherPay  ...     TotalPay  TotalPayBenefits  Year  Notes         Agency Status
    0   1     NATHANIEL FORD  GENERAL MANAGER-METROPOLITAN TRANSIT AUTHORITY  167411.18         0.0  400184.25  ...    567595.43         567595.43  2011    NaN  San Francisco    NaN
    1   2       GARY JIMENEZ                 CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT)  155966.02   245131.88  137811.38  ...    538909.28         538909.28  2011    NaN  San Francisco    NaN
    2   3     ALBERT PARDINI                 CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT)  212739.13   106088.18    16452.6  ...    335279.91         335279.91  2011    NaN  San Francisco    NaN
    3   4  CHRISTOPHER CHONG            WIRE ROPE CABLE MAINTENANCE MECHANIC    77916.0    56120.71   198306.9  ...    332343.61         332343.61  2011    NaN  San Francisco    NaN
    4   5    PATRICK GARDNER    DEPUTY CHIEF OF DEPARTMENT,(FIRE DEPARTMENT)   134401.6      9737.0  182234.59  ...    326373.19         326373.19  2011    NaN  San Francisco    NaN

    [5 rows x 13 columns]
    >>> EmpSal = salDataF.groupby('Year').mean()
    KeyboardInterrupt
    >>> salDataF.groupby('Year').mean()
                Id      TotalPay  TotalPayBenefits  Notes
    Year
    2011   18080.0  71744.103871      71744.103871    NaN
    2012   54542.5  74113.262265     100553.229232    NaN
    2013   91728.5  77611.443142     101440.519714    NaN
    2014  129593.0  75463.918140     100250.918884    NaN
    >>> EmpSal = salDataF.groupby('Year').mean()['BasePay']
```

> Error:  KeyError: 'BasePay'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is problem `BasePay` is not numeric, so `salDataF.groupby('Year').mean()` [exclude all non numeric columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns) by design.

Solution is first try [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
salDataF['BasePay'] = salDataF['BasePay'].astype(float)
```

...and if failed because some non numeric data use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaN`s

```
salDataF['BasePay'] = pd.to_numeric(salDataF['BasePay'], errors='coerce')
```

and then better is select column before `mean`:

```
EmpSal = salDataF.groupby('Year')['BasePay'].mean()
```

Comment: @pygo -  opps, mea culpa. Need `salDataF` instead `df`, edited answer.

Comment: @pygo - yes, then need `salDataF['BasePay'] = pd.to_numeric(salDataF['BasePay'], errors='coerce')`